# openstack installation rally error

Tags: centos, centos7, python, openstack, openstack-neutron

I've got a problem throught installation of openstack in a VM Centos7

the error is:

```
[root@localhost ~(keystone_admin)]# rally deployment create --fromenv --name=existing
Command failed, please check log for more info
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 CRITICAL rally [-] ImportError: cannot import name VariableManager
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/bin/rally", line 10, in <module>
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     sys.exit(main())
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/cli/main.py", line 38, in main
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     return cliutils.run(sys.argv, categories)
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/cli/cliutils.py", line 661, in run
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "<string>", line 2, in create
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/plugins/__init__.py", line 42, in ensure_plugins_are_loaded
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     load()
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/plugins/__init__.py", line 32, in load
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     discover.import_modules_from_package("rally.plugins")
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/common/plugin/discover.py", line 60, in import_modules_from_package
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     module_name)
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/importutils.py", line 73, in import_module
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     __import__(import_str)
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rally/plugins/openstack/hook/fault_injection.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     import os_faults
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/os_faults/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     from os_faults.ansible import executor
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/os_faults/ansible/executor.py", line 24, in <module>
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally     from ansible.vars import VariableManager
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally ImportError: cannot import name VariableManager
2019-09-02 01:58:54.144 17869 ERROR rally
```

I've searched on web but I haven't found solutions

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Checking further have you installed "python-octaviaclient" package Also,
have you tried: "rally db recreate"

Comment: yes python-octaviaclient is installed and rally db recreate doesn't correct the problem

Answer (score -1):

looks like you're about to use rally 0.9.1, so bump your ansible version. For example `pip install ansible==2.3`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, how can you tell which version the OP was using and why should he upgrade?